# Read phantom console.log without killing phantom (phantom.exit())

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am reading a webpage where I have to login and then pass my search string.

Every time I want to read the results, I have to call phantom.exit() I do get the results but for every query I have to login again and that kills performance of my script.

Is there a way to read the results that's in memory without killing phantom?

Below is a quick snippet where I am getting the URL and Tel number for a given company. Only way I would get that info on console is to call phanton.exit()

```
 if (url == infoPage) {
        page.evaluate(function () {
            if ($('.companyURL > a')
                .length > 0) {
                console.info($('.companyURL > a')
                    .text());
            } else {
                console.info("Company URL not present");
            } if ($('.tel')
                .text()) {
                console.info($('.tel')
                    .text());
            } else {
                console.info("Company Telephone not present");
            }
        });
        phantom.exit();
```

Comment: Did you try using .log instead of .info?

Comment: log is blocked by the site we are scrapping :) so info but would log allow me to get data on console w/o calling phantom.exit?

Comment: Hmm not sure but I've noticed phantom.js's console object isn't as robust as chrome or firefox, so it's up to you to see what happens.

Comment: do you think I can use page.onConsoleMessage and not exit phantom?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why you can't specify a function to put the console log into a variable.

```
var evaluatedConsole = "";

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    evaluatedConsole += msg + "\n";
};
```